# Rules vs Loaders in Webpack - What's the Difference?

Tags: webpack

In some Webpack examples, you see reference to a "rules" array:

```
module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
          fallback: 'style-loader',
          //resolve-url-loader may be chained before sass-loader if necessary
          use: ['css-loader', 'sass-loader']
        })
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new ExtractTextPlugin('style.css')
    //if you want to pass in options, you can do so:
    //new ExtractTextPlugin({
    //  filename: 'style.css'
    //})
  ]
}
```

(https://github.com/webpack-contrib/extract-text-webpack-plugin)

And in other, a loaders array:

```
var ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin");
module.exports = {
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
                    loader: "css-loader"
                })
            },
            { test: /\.png$/, loader: "file-loader" }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new ExtractTextPlugin({
            filename: "style.css",
            allChunks: true
        })
    ]
};
```

(https://github.com/webpack/webpack/tree/master/examples/css-bundle)

What is the difference? Which should be used?

Comment: https://webpack.js.org/guides/migrating/#module-loaders-is-now-module-rules

Comment: now at https://webpack.js.org/migrate/3/#module-loaders-is-now-module-rules

Answer (score 97):

`Loaders` are used in Webpack 1
`Rules` are used in Webpack 2+

#### According to the [migrating docs](https://webpack.js.org/migrate/3/#moduleloaders-is-now-modulerules) at the official Webpack site.

> **`module.loaders` is now `module.rules`**
>
> The old loader configuration was superseded by a more powerful rules system, which allows configuration of loaders and more. For compatibility reasons, the old `module.loaders` syntax is still valid and the old names are parsed. The new naming conventions are easier to understand and are a good reason to upgrade the configuration to using `module.rules`.

#### Example of Delta

```
  module: {
-   loaders: [
+   rules: [
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
-       loaders: [
-         "style-loader",
-         "css-loader?modules=true"
+       use: [
+         {
+           loader: "style-loader"
+         },
+         {
+           loader: "css-loader",
+           options: {
+             modules: true
+           }
+         }
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.jsx$/,
        loader: "babel-loader", // Do not use "use" here
        options: {
          // ...
        }
      }
    ]
  }
```

Comment: Any official reference?

Comment: https://webpack.js.org/guides/migrating/#module-loaders-is-now-module-rules

Comment: When I added babel integration I've used loaders section from an example without paying attention to this aspect, but my project used rules, which went after loaders section. I spent few hours investigating why babel is not working!!! because rules just silently overrides loaders section :(