# Difference between module.loaders and module.rules in webpack.config.js

Tags: typescript, webpack, webpack.config.js

I am looking to use a typescript loader with Babel, I see this:

https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-loader

```
module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      { 
        test: /\.tsx?$/, 
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'ts-loader', 
            options: {
              transpileOnly: true
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

why use `module.rules` instead of `module.loaders`? For example, I would have expected to see this instead:

```
module.exports = {
  module: {
    loaders: [    // loaders instead of rules
      { 
        test: /\.tsx?$/, 
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'ts-loader', 
            options: {
              transpileOnly: true
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

what's the difference?

Comment: See if can get some help from https://webpack.js.org/guides/migrating/#module-loaders-is-now-module-rules

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43002099/rules-vs-loaders-in-webpack-whats-the-difference

Answer (score 3):

Rules were interduced webpack 2. Loaders you are seeing is a part of webpack 1.