# ERROR in Entry module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'babel-loader'

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, reactjs, webpack

I am a beginner to react. While setting up the installation and loading up all the dependencies, I finally run the `npm start` command but this generates the error **ERROR in Entry module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'babel-loader' in 'C:\Users\me\Documents\React\react-playlist'** I have performed all the installation steps correctly. I have also attached the [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qoCoS.png) of the project folder. I also got webpack installed globally v 3.10.0 but that also didn't work. I also tried by inserting resolve loaders code in package.json file but that also didn't work. Here is the error [picture.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8iC8q.png)

P.S.: I'm following this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f7TmMBMLJ90&list=PL4cUxeGkcC9i0_2FF-WhtRIfIJ1lXlTZR&index=3)

Below is the code of my project.
Package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "react-playlist",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "All the course files for the Net Ninja React tutorial playlist on YouTube",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "npm run build",
    "build": "webpack -d && webpack-dev-server --content-base src/ --inline --hot --port 1234"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/iamshaunjp/react-playlist.git"
  },
  "author": "me",
  "license": "MIT",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/iamshaunjp/react-playlist/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/iamshaunjp/react-playlist#readme",
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.2",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.6.1",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "webpack": "^3.10.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.9.7"
  }
}
```

Webpack.config.js

```
var path = require('path');

module.exports = {

    entry: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src') + '/app/index.js',
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist') + '/app',
        filename: 'bundle.js',
        publicPath: '/app/'
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                include: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                query: {
                    presets: ['react', 'es2015', 'env']
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                loader: 'style-loader!css-loader'
            }
        ]
    } };
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>React - Novice to Ninja!</title>
    </head>
    <body>
      <script src="/app/bundle.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Make sure to install all the packages first using `npm install` followed by npm start

Comment: @cdoshi it is already up to date.

Comment: webpack is deprecating `module.loaders`. Try using `module.rules` instead: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43002099/rules-vs-loaders-in-webpack-whats-the-difference

Comment: @casraf It threw a huge error starting with "options/query provided without loader (use loader + options)". That not a right move I think,

Answer (score 6):

It looks like `module.loaders` section of your `webpack` config is for older versions of `webpack` while you are using the latest (3.10.0). This is how it should look with the latest `webpack` for your configuration:

```
module: {
  rules: [
    { 
      test: /\.js$/,
      include: [
        path.resolve(__dirname, "src")
      ],
      use: {
        loader: 'babel-loader'
      },
      options: {
        presets: ['react', 'es2015', 'env']
      }
    },
    {
       test: /\.css$/,
       use: {
         loader: 'style-loader!css-loader'
       }     
    }
  ]
```

All `webpack` options are described in the docs in the configuration section [here](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/#options).

Answer (score 5):

Please see this post for details [(ERROR in multi) Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'babel/loader'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58230055/error-in-multi-module-not-found-error-cant-resolve-babel-loader/64491950#64491950) and execute this command:

```
npm install -D babel-loader @babel/core @babel/preset-env webpack
```

Source: https://github.com/babel/babel-loader