# (ERROR in multi) Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'babel/loader'

Tags: webpack

[This image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k7wkB.jpg) contains folder structure and webpack.config.js file. When I open webpack-dev-server, I get the following error:

```
ERROR in multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080 ./src/js/index.js ./src/scss/master.scss
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'babel/loader' in 'C:\wamp64\www\o\omd'
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080 ./src/js/index.js ./src/scss/master.scss main[0]
```

Note than I have installed `babel/loader` inside `node_modules`. Any clue would be appreciated!
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the correct formula, after all, below `scss` you are well declared

```
{
  test: /\.js$/,
  exclude: /node_modules/,
  use: {
    loader: 'babel-loader',
  },
},
```

I suggest adding the presets in a separate file. Create `.babelrc` file and add to it.

```
{
 "presets": [
   [
    "@babel/preset-env"
   ]
 ]
}
```

Look here - [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57275695/10424385)

Comment: oopsie! simple typo: it's `babel-loader`, not `babel/loader`. :P

Answer (score 0):

Please note that I also had the same problem so to resolve it I installed `babel-loader` according to their website (see https://github.com/babel/babel-loader):

```
npm install -D babel-loader @babel/core @babel/preset-env webpack
```