# Facing issue while upgrading Angular 11 app to Angular 12

Tags: angular, angular-cli, single-spa, angular12, single-spa-angular

When we are trying to update our Angular 11 application(Single SPA micro frontend) to Angular 12 we are facing bellow issue.

Error on console when trying to run this app:

```
An unhandled exception occurred: Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialised using a configuration object that does not match the API schema.
```

- configuration.output has an unknown property 'chunkLoadingGlobal'. These properties are valid:
  object { auxiliaryComment?, chunkCallbackName?, chunkFilename?, chunkLoadTimeout?, crossOriginLoading?, devtoolFallbackModuleFilenameTemplate?, devtoolLineToLine?, devtoolModuleFilenameTemplate?, devtoolNamespace?, filename?, futureEmitAssetss?, globalObject?, hashDigest?, hashDigestLength?, hashFunction?, hashSalt?, hotUpdateChunkFilename?, hotUpdateFunction?, hotUpdateMainFilename?, jsonpFunction?, jsonpScriptType?, library?, libraryExport?, libraryTarget?, path?, pathinfo?, publicPath?, sourceMapFilename?, sourcePrefix?, strictModuleExceptionHandling?, umdNamedDefine?, webassemblyModuleFilename? }-> Options affecting the output of the compilation. `output` options tell webpack how to write the compiled files to disk.
  See "C:\Users\newUser\AppData\Local\Temp\ng-UOeNLu\angular-errors.log" for further details.

Package.json:

```
    "name": "my-app",
    "version": "0.0.0",
    "scripts": {
      "ng": "ng",
      "start": "npm run serve",
      "devstart": "ng serve --aot=false",
      "build": "npm run build",
      "test": "ng test"
    },
    "private": true,
    "dependencies": {
      "@angular/animations": "~12.0.5",
      "@angular/cdk": "^12.0.5",
      "@angular/common": "~12.0.5",
      "@angular/compiler": "~12.0.5",
      "@angular/core": "~12.0.5",
      "@angular/forms": "~12.0.5",
      "@angular/material": "^12.0.5",
      "@angular/platform-browser": "~12.0.5",
      "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~12.0.5",
      "@angular/router": "~12.0.5",
      "@material-extended/mde": "^3.0.3",
      "bootstrap-4-grid": "^3.4.0",
      "highcharts": "^8.1.2",
      "html2canvas": "^1.0.0-rc.7",
      "htmldiff-js": "^1.0.5",
      "http-server": "^0.12.3",
      "jquery": "^3.5.1",
      "jspdf": "^2.1.1",
      "mat-table-exporter": "^9.0.0",
      "ngx-mat-select-search": "^2.1.2",
      "ng2-file-upload": "^1.4.0",
      "ngx-matomo": "^0.1.4",
      "ngx-summernote": "^0.8.0",
      "ngx-order-pipe": "^2.0.4",
      "rxjs": "~6.5.4",
      "single-spa": ">=4.0.0",
      "single-spa-angular": "5.0.1",
      "tslib": "^2.0.0",
      "summernote": "^0.8.18",
      "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
      "@angular-builders/custom-webpack": "9.2.1-beta.0",
      "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.1102.13",
      "@angular/cli": "~12.0.5",
      "@angular/compiler-cli": "~12.0.5",
      "@angular/language-service": "~12.0.5",
      "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
      "@types/jasmine": "~3.6.0",
      "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
      "codelyzer": "^6.0.0",
      "jasmine-core": "~3.6.0",
      "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
      "karma": "~5.0.0",
      "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
      "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.2",
      "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
      "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
      "protractor": "~7.0.0",
      "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
      "tslint": "~6.1.0",
      "typescript": "~4.2.4"
    }
  }
```

Angular.json:

````
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "my-app": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {
        "@schematics/angular:component": {
          "style": "scss"
        }
      },
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-builders/custom-webpack:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/my-app",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.single-spa.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "aot": true,
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "./node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css",
              "./node_modules/bootstrap-4-grid/scss/grid.scss",
              "src/styles.scss",
              "node_modules/summernote/dist/summernote-lite.min.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [
              "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
              "node_modules/summernote/dist/summernote-lite.min.js"
            ],
            "customWebpackConfig": {
              "path": "extra-webpack.config.js",
              "libraryName": "my-app",
              "libraryTarget": "umd"
            }
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "none",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "2mb",
                  "maximumError": "5mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "6kb",
                  "maximumError": "20kb"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-builders/custom-webpack:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "my-app:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "my-app:build:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "my-app:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "karma.conf.js",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "./node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css",
              "src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "tsconfig.app.json",
              "tsconfig.spec.json",
              "e2e/tsconfig.json"
            ],
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        },
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
          "options": {
            "protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.js",
            "devServerTarget": "my-app:serve"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "devServerTarget": "my-app:serve:production"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "defaultProject": "my-app",
  "cli": {
    "analytics": false
  }
}```
````

Comment: Does this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/42068953/9721056 solve your issue?

Comment: Can you please post your angular.json and package.json? Are you upgrading your global install first, then running ng update @angular/core @angular/cli at your project root where your package.json is?

Comment: @cklimowski I have edited the question to add package.json and angular.json

Comment: Are you upgrading your global @angular/cli install first using npm i -g @angular/cli@12.0.5, then running ng update @angular/core @angular/cli?

Comment: @cklimowski yes I am upgrading the global cli first and then running the ng update

Comment: @Dnyaneshwar were you able to resolve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I encountered the same issue. Changing the versions of certain dependencies and `devDependencies` in `package.json` resolved it for me.

Changed dependencies to have the following:

- `"single-spa": "5.9.3"`
- `"single-spa-angular": "5.0.2"`

Changed the dev dependencies to have the following:

- `"@angular-builders/custom-webpack": "12.1.3"`
- `"@angular-devkit/build-angular": "12.2.16"`