# webpack build successful but when start it return webpack config on terminal and close with ValidationError: Invalid configuration object

Tags: webpack, require, webpack-5, module-export

using webpack to build and run the vanilla javascript project which have node js and express js, webpack build working fine  but  running after making some changes in **webpack.config.js** file, it stopped working although build command run successfully

below is the

### package.json

```
 "scripts": {
    "client": "webpack --mode production --config webpack.client.config.js",
    "server": "webpack --mode production --config webpack.server.config.js",
    "clean": "rd /s /q dist >nul 2>&1|echo.>null",
    "start": "node ./dist/server.js",
    "build": "npm run client && npm run server",
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.7",
    "@babel/eslint-parser": "^7.22.9",
    "@babel/register": "^7.0.0",
    "babel-loader": "^9.1.0",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^11.0.0",
    "css-loader": "^6.7.3",
    "eslint": "^8.30.0",
    "eslint-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "html-loader": "^4.2.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.5.0",
    "http-proxy-middleware": "^2.0.6",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^2.7.2",
    "style-loader": "^3.3.1",
    "webpack": "^5.75.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^5.1.4",
    "webpack-dev-middleware": "^6.0.1",
    "webpack-hot-middleware": "^2.25.4",
    "webpack-node-externals": "^3.0.0"
  },
```

using below **webpack.config.js**

#### webpack.config.js ( config as object )

```js
const plugins = require("./webpack.plugin.config");
const modules = require("./webpack.modules.config");

const baseConfig = {
    entry: { home: './home.js', server: './server/server-dev.js' },
    devServer: {
      static: "./dist",
      open: true,
      hot: true
    },
    output: {
      path: './dist/',
      publicPath: "/",
      filename: "[name].js",
      chunkFilename: "[name].js",
      assetModuleFilename: "assets/[hash][ext][query]",
      clean: true
    },
    plugins: plugins,
    module: modules,
    mode: "production",
    target: "node", // "web"
    node: {
      __dirname: false, 
      __filename: false
    },
    externals: [nodeExternals()],
    devtool: "eval-source-map",
    resolve: {
      extensions: [".html", ".js", ".json", ".css"]
    }
  };

  module.exports = baseConfig;
```

build working fine and start also working fine.

now

I want to cature *env* and *args* value so convert config into method as below

#### webpack.config.js ( config as method )

```js
const nodeExternals = require("webpack-node-externals");

const plugins = require("./webpack.plugin.config");
const modules = require("./webpack.modules.config");

const config = (env, args) => {
  console.log(env, args);
  return {
    entry: { 
        home: './home.js',
        server: './server/server-dev.js'
    },
    devServer: {
      static: "./dist",
      open: true,
      hot: true
    },
    output: {
      path: "./dist",
      publicPath: "/",
      filename: "[name].js",
      chunkFilename: "[name].js",
      assetModuleFilename: "assets/[hash][ext][query]",
      globalObject: "typeof self !== 'undefined' ? self : this",
      clean: true
    },
    plugins: plugins,
    module: modules,
    mode: "production",
    target: "node", 
    node: {
      __dirname: false,
      __filename: false
    },
    externals: [nodeExternals()],
    devtool: "eval-source-map",
    resolve: {
      extensions: [".html", ".js", ".json", ".css"]
    }
  };
};

module.exports = config;
```

here webpack build job running fine but when start it `npm run start`, it just return long webpack config and stops with below error

> ValidationError: Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialized using a configuration object that does not match the API schema.

- configuration should be an object:

so error says it require object, so change last line to

#### trial 1

`module.exports = config();`

but here config() require 2 parameter so it is not working

#### trial 2

now  directly write module.exports against method as below

```js
module.export = (env.args) => {
```

but still facing same error.

#### trail 3

change config object property using function

const baseConfig = { ... };
module.exports = (env, args) => {
console.log(env, args);
baseConfig .mode = args.mode;
return baseConfig;
};

but same error on start.

someone please help to find the issue and suggest how to fix

checked [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42060243/invalid-configuration-object-webpack-has-been-initialised-using-a-configuration) but all solution doesnt work because all ther areusing object config

---

### update

seems like the issue is in *server-dev.js* file which is using webpack.config.js inside it and here is the content ( shared the relevent code for brevity )

#### server-dev.js

```js
import express from "express";
import fs from "fs";
import path from "path";
import { webpack } from "webpack";
import webpackDevMiddleware from "webpack-dev-middleware";
import webpackHotMiddleware from "webpack-hot-middleware";
import config from "../../webpack.config.js";


const app = express();

const router = express.Router();

const currentDirectory = process.cwd(); // current directory

const DIST_DIR = path.join(path.resolve(currentDirectory, "dist"));
const HTML_DIR = path.join(DIST_DIR, "html");
const HTML_FILE = path.join(HTML_DIR, "index.html");
const compiler = webpack(config);

app.use(
  webpackDevMiddleware(compiler, {
    publicPath: config.output.publicPath
  })
);

app.use(webpackHotMiddleware(compiler));
```